# [[Construct]] internal method

Tags: javascript

What is the result of calling `[[Construct]]` internal method? The spec said the follwoing:

> Creates an object. Invoked via the new operator. The arguments to the
>   SpecOp are the arguments passed to the new operator. Objects that
>   implement this internal method are called constructors.

It isn't clear from this quote what exactly object will be created after the `[[Construct]]` is call.

Comment: Which spec are you reading, ES5 or ES6?

Comment: @Bergi At that time, there was only ES5.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't notice how old the question is. Still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Bergi Well, I''d not say that I'm looking for it every day :), but it would be interesting to look at the formal explanation...

Answer (score 1):

The `[[Construct]]` property is the property of the function itself and nothing else. It is called only when a constructor function needs it to construct a new object and it simply creates a new object and does memory allocation after which it calls the `[[Call]]` internal method for the function itself, to continue construction.