# How to check if a Javascript function is a constructor

Tags: javascript

I noticed not all the Javascript functions are constructors.

```
var obj = Function.prototype;
console.log(typeof obj === 'function'); //true
obj(); //OK
new obj(); //TypeError: obj is not a constructor
```

Question 1: How do I check if a function is a constructor so that it can be called with `new` keyword?

Question 2: When I create a function, is it possible to make it **NOT** a constructor?

Comment: Interesting are `Function` and `Function.prototype` the only `function`'s that aren't constructors?

Comment: Function is a construtor. new Function(); works.

Comment: Just check if the type is a function.

Comment: Symbol too is not a function constructor. console.log(new Symbol); //TypeError: Symbol is not a constructor

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A little bit of background:

ECMAScript 6+ distinguishes between *callable* (can be called without `new`) and *constructable* (can be called with `new`) functions:

- Functions created via the arrow functions syntax or via a method definition in classes or object literals are *not constructable*.
- Functions created via the `class` syntax are *not callable*.
- Functions created in any other way (function expression/declaration, `Function` constructor) are callable and constructable.
- Built-in functions are not constructrable unless explicitly stated otherwise.

**About `Function.prototype`**

`Function.prototype` is a so called [*built-in function*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-built-in-function) [that is not constructable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-createintrinsics). From the spec:

> Built-in function objects that are not identified as constructors do not implement the `[[Construct]]` internal method unless otherwise specified in the description of a particular function.

The value of `Function.prototype` is create at the very beginning of the runtime initialization. It is basically an empty function and it is not explicitly stated that it is constructable.

---

> How do I check if an function is a constructor so that it can be called with a new?

There isn't a built-in way to do that. You can `try` to call the function with `new`, and either inspect the error or return `true`:

```
function isConstructor(f) {
  try {
    new f();
  } catch (err) {
    // verify err is the expected error and then
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

However, that approach is not failsafe since functions can have side effects, so after calling `f`, you don't know which state the environment is in.

Also, this will only tell you whether a function *can* be called as a constructor, not if it is *intended* to be called as constructor. For that you have to look at the documentation or the implementation of the function.

**Note:** There should never be a reason to use a test like this one in a production environment. Whether or not a function is supposed to be called with `new` should be discernable from its documentation.

> When I create a function, how do I make it NOT a constructor?

To create a function is truly not *constructable*, you can use an arrow function:

```
var f = () => console.log('no constructable');
```

Arrow functions are by definition not constructable. Alternatively you could define a function as a method of an object or a class.

Otherwise you could check whether a function is called with `new` (or something similar) by checking it's `this` value and throw an error if it is:

```
function foo() {
  if (this instanceof foo) {
    throw new Error("Don't call 'foo' with new");
  }
}
```

Of course, since there are other ways to set the value of `this`, there can be false positives.

---

**Examples**

```js
function isConstructor(f) {
  try {
    new f();
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.message.indexOf('is not a constructor') >= 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function test(f, name) {
  console.log(`${name} is constructable: ${isConstructor(f)}`);
}

function foo(){}
test(foo, 'function declaration');
test(function(){}, 'function expression');
test(()=>{}, 'arrow function');

class Foo {}
test(Foo, 'class declaration');
test(class {}, 'class expression');

test({foo(){}}.foo, 'object method');

class Foo2 {
  static bar() {}
  bar() {}
}
test(Foo2.bar, 'static class method');
test(new Foo2().bar, 'class method');

test(new Function(), 'new Function()');
```

Comment: If constructor has parameters isConstructor returns false.

Comment: 'Whether or not a function is supposed to be called with new should be discernible from its documentation.'- not at all. JS is a duck-typed language. There are valid scenarios where one needs to do some sort of run-time 'type' checking on parameters and whether a function is constructable is one of those.

Comment: What about `const isConstructor = fn => typeof fn === 'function' && 'prototype' in fn` ? I can see arrow functions don't have a prototype

Comment: @Frondor: That would probably be good enough for 99% of all cases. I still have to add that it's of course possible to manually define a `prototype` property on an arrow function. Also see this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922531/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-function-is-a-constructor/40922715?noredirect=1#comment82963091_46320004

Comment: By the way. Classes are 'callable'. They implement [[Call]] internal, they just throw.

Comment: "There should never be a reason to use a test like this one in a production environment." - I disagree. At the moment, I'm trying to distinguish whether the caller is passing a constructor or a function that returns a promise that returns a constructor, both of which should be valid inputs for the API I am working on.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Fair enough. I would probably have the API be a function that returns a constructor or a promise resolving to a constructor. Then the implementation could be just `const constr = await constructorProvider();` (but of course that might not be suitable for your situation).

Answer (score 37):

You are looking for if a function has a [`[[Construct]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) internal method. The internal method [`IsConstructor`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isconstructor) details the steps:

> `IsConstructor(argument)`
>
> ```
> ReturnIfAbrupt(argument).  // (Check if an exception has been thrown; Not important.)  
> If Type(argument) is not Object, return false.  // argument === Object(argument), or (typeof argument === 'Object' || typeof argument === 'function')  
> If argument has a [[Construct]] internal method, return true.  
> Return false.
> ```

Now we need to find places where `IsConstructor` is used, but `[[Construct]]` isn't called (usually by the [`Construct`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-construct) internal method.)

I found that it is used in the `String` function's `newTarget` ([`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) in js), which can be used with [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct):

```
function is_constructor(f) {
  try {
    Reflect.construct(String, [], f);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

(I could have used anything really, like `Reflect.construct(Array, [], f);`, but `String` was first)

Which yields the following results:

```
// true
is_constructor(function(){});
is_constructor(class A {});
is_constructor(Array);
is_constructor(Function);
is_constructor(new Function);

// false
is_constructor();
is_constructor(undefined);
is_constructor(null);
is_constructor(1);
is_constructor(new Number(1));
is_constructor(Array.prototype);
is_constructor(Function.prototype);
is_constructor(() => {})
is_constructor({method() {}}.method)
```

---

<note>

The only value that I found it didn't work for is `Symbol`, which, although `new Symbol` throws a `TypeError: Symbol is not a constructor` in Firefox, `is_constructor(Symbol) === true`. This is *technically* the correct answer, as `Symbol` *does* have a `[[Construct]]` internal method (Which means it can also be subclassed), but using `new` or `super` is special cased for `Symbol` to throw an error (So, `Symbol` is a constructor, the error message is wrong, it just can't be used as one.) You can just add `if (f === Symbol) return false;` to the top though.

The same for something like this:

```
function not_a_constructor() {
  if (new.target) throw new TypeError('not_a_constructor is not a constructor.');
  return stuff(arguments);
}

is_constructor(not_a_constructor);  // true
new not_a_constructor;  // TypeError: not_a_constructor is not a constructor.
```

So the intentions of the function of being a constructor can't be gotton like this (Until somthing like `Symbol.is_constructor` or some other flag is added).

</note>

Comment: This is a clever solution, but aside from `Function.prototype`, you would get the same results by checking whether the `typeof f === "function"`.

Comment: @JeffRose Sorry, I didn't seem to add enough negative examples. Specifically the arrow function. `is_constructor(() => {})` is false.

Comment: This only works for constructors without params I believe.

is_constructor(URL); will fail for instance

Comment: @LodeMichels This does work with constructors with parameters. Not sure why it wouldn't. `is_constructor(URL)` returns `true`.

Answer (score 20):

With ES6+ Proxies, one can test for `[[Construct]]` without actually invoking the constructor. Here's a snippet:

```
const handler={construct(){return handler}} //Must return ANY object, so reuse one
const isConstructor=x=>{
    try{
        return !!(new (new Proxy(x,handler))())
    }catch(e){
        return false
    }
}
```

If the passed item isn't an object, the `Proxy` constructor throws an error. If it's not a constructable object, then `new` throws an error. But if it's a constructable object, then it returns the `handler` object without invoking its constructor, which is then not-notted into `true`.

As you might expect, `Symbol` is still considered a constructor. That's because it is, and the implementation merely throws an error when `[[Construct]]` is invoked. This could be the case on ANY user-defined function that throws an error when `new.target` exists, so it doesn't seem right to specifically weed it out as an additional check, but feel free to do so if you find that to be helpful.

Answer (score 19):

There is a quick and easy way of determining if function can be instantiated, without having to resort to try-catch statements (which can not be optimized by v8)

```
function isConstructor(obj) {
  return !!obj.prototype && !!obj.prototype.constructor.name;
}
```

1. First we check if object is part of a prototype chain.
2. Then we exclude anonymous functions

There is a caveat, which is: [**functions named inside a definition**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) will still incur a name property and thus pass this check, so caution is required when relying on tests for function constructors.

In the following example, the function is not anonymous but in fact is called 'myFunc'. It's prototype can be extended as any JS class.

```
let myFunc = function () {};
```

Comment: Why would you want to exclude anonymous functions ? They are constructables.

Comment: I would prefer `Object.hasOwnProperty("prototype")` for this function. BTW, while most constructables do have `.prototype`'s, some like bound functions don't, but they are still constructables. This is because constructability does not have a direct relationship with `.prototype`, it all has to do with the internal [`[[construct]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874128/construct-internal-method) method. _So, while this is a decent solution for many cases, it is not entirely bulletproof (as you have noted)._

Comment: `isConstructor(class {})` returns `false`

Comment: @doubleOrt In addition to that, having a `prototype` property does not mean that function is a constructor. For example, built in `Symbol` has a `prototype` property. However, `new Symbol()` throws [not a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor) TypeError.

Comment: Isn't it kind of silly for the ECMAScript specification to specify rules and implementation steps (like testing for `[[construct]]` that don't have a clear implementation in regular ECMAScript?  Somehow that seems a bit broken.  The best we can apparently do is to approximate it for most scenarios.  I'm trying to implement a polyfill for a proposed new method and trying to follow the proposed specification, but that apparently isn't' entirely possible because there's no way to test if something truly is a constructor.

Comment: @jfriend00 I came across this neat dependency injection library for js which I really like the approach of to this problem https://brandi.js.org/

Answer (score 6):

If the function is a constructor then it will have a "prototype" member which in turn has a "constructor" member that is equal to the function itself.

```
function isConstructor(func) {
    return typeof func === 'function' && !!func.prototype && func.prototype.constructor === func;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the parenthesis. Try `isConstructor(false)`. SCNR :-)

Comment: And to quote [@doubleOrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922531/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-function-is-a-constructor#comment82963091_46320004): "*while most constructables do have `.prototype`'s, some like bound functions don't, but they are still constructables. This is because constructability does not have a direct relationship with `.prototype`*"

Comment: Above is named `isConstructor` not is `isConstructable`, I mean, it's okay that this will return `false` for `Bound-constructors`, because "bound" means to redirect to something, instead of being a real constructor directly.

Answer (score 3):

There is a quick and easy way of determining if function can be instantiated, without having to resort to try-catch statements (which can not be optimized by v8)

```
function isConstructor(value) {
    return !!value && !!value.prototype && !!value.prototype.constructor;
}
```

1. First, we check `value` is truthy.
2. Then checks if `value` is part of a prototype chain.
3. At last, simply checks if `constructor` is set ;-)

> **Note** that above is named `isConstructor` not is `isConstructable`, I mean, this will return `false` for `Bound-constructors` as said in comments, because "bound" means to redirect to something, instead of being a real constructor directly.
>
> So this answers title's "`check ... is constructor`" question, but not later "`check ... can be called with new`" question.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> const myClazz = {method() {}};
> myClazz.method = myClazz.method.bind(myClazz);
>
> // We can call above with new keyword.
> new (myClazz.method);
>
> // But it's just a callback.
> if (isConstructor(myClass))
>    throw new Error('expected to return false for arrow-functions and similar.');
> ```

### Unit-testing

Below is based on `Jasmine`.

```js
// Change import to wherever your common functions are 
// (for me they're in src directory, outside of tests directory).
import * as common from '../common-tools';

let isMyClassCalled = false;
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
      isMyClassCalled = true;
  }
}

describe('App isConstructor tool', () => {
    it('should detect constructor', function () {
        detect(class A {});
        detect(Array);
        detect(Function);
        detect(new Function);
        detect({method() {}}.method);
    });

    it('should NOT detect as constructor', function () {
        noDetect();
        noDetect(undefined);
        noDetect(null);
        noDetect(1);
        noDetect(new Number(1));
        noDetect(new (function(){}));
        noDetect(Array.prototype);
        noDetect(Function.prototype);
        // Commented because optimizations convert below into function.
        //noDetect((() => {}));
    });

    it('should NOT detect bound constructors', function () {
        const clazz = {method() {}};
        clazz.method = clazz.method.bind(clazz);
        noDetect(clazz.method);
    });

    it('should never call constructor', function () {
        common.isConstructor(MyClass);
        expect(isMyClassCalled).toBe(false);
    });

    function detect(value, expecting = true) {
        expect(common.isConstructor(value))
            .withContext('For "' + value + '" value')
            .toBe(expecting);
    }

    function noDetect(value) {
        detect(value, false);
    }
});
```

### Alternative

All above tests pass with below as well.

```
function isConstructor(value) {
    return typeof value === 'function' && !!value.prototype && value.prototype.constructor === value;
}
```

Comment: I believe `detect((() => {}))` should be in the other test case and be `noDetect((() => {}))`. After all, arrow functions are not constructors. FWIW, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862312/218196 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53112237/218196 already mentioned this approach.

Comment: @FelixKling I just checked and my `WebPack` was optimizing that into "`detect(function () {});`", now this approves my answer even more (after I fix the tests), because arrow-functions are auto "bound" ;-)

Comment: what about `Boolean(value?.prototype?.constructor);`?

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird The OP is about JavaScript, but as long as that compiles to my JS code, the results should be same.

Comment: @Top-Master that *is* js...?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many workarounds but it didn't satisfy my needs, So i made my own workaround by using reflection metadata.

**GOAL:** Check if the current Function has it's own __**class**__ metadata which represent if this function is a constructor or not.

- npm install reflect-metadata
- Create class decorator factory **@Class()**
- Create a helper function to check **__class__** metadata attached to the current function or not.

**NOTE:** The only way in this workaround to distinguish between Constructor Function and Normal Function or Class is by using Class Decorator **@Class()**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

type Constructor<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function Class() {
    return function (target: Constructor) {
        if (!!Reflect.getOwnMetadata('__class__', target)) {
            throw new Error(`Cannot apply @Class decorator on ${target.name} multiple times.`);
        }
        Reflect.defineMetadata('__class__', target, target);
    };
}

function isConstructor<T>(type: Constructor<T>): boolean {
    if (typeof type !== 'function') return false;
    return !!Reflect.getOwnMetadata('__class__', type);
}

/*
 * ------------------
 * Example
 * ------------------
 */

@Class()
class ServiceClass1 {}

class ServiceClass2 {}

function Test() {}

console.log(isConstructor(ServiceClass1)) // true
console.log(isConstructor(ServiceClass2)) // false
console.log(isConstructor(Test)) // false
```

Answer (score -1):

For question 1, what about this helper?

```
Function.isConstructor = ({ prototype }) => Boolean(prototype) && Boolean(prototype.constructor)

Function.isConstructor(class {}); // true
Function.isConstructor(function() {}); // true
Function.isConstructor(() => {}); // false
Function.isConstructor("a string"); // false
```

For question 2, the arrow function is the solution. It cannot be used as a constructor since it does not rely on the same scope as a regular function and does not have a prototype (definition of instances, similar to class definition for real OOP)

```
const constructable = function() { console.log(this); };
const callable = () => { console.log(this); };

constructable(); // Window {}
callable(); // Window {}
new constructable(); // aConstructableFunction {}
new callable(); // Uncaught TypeError: callable is not a constructor
```

Answer (score -1):

As an addition to [Felix Kling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40922715/3395831), even if a function is not constructable, we can still use it like a constructor if it has a `prototype` property. We can do this with the help of `Object.create()`. Example:

```js
// The built-in object Symbol is not constructable, even though it has a "prototype" property:
new Symbol
// TypeError: Symbol is not a constructor.
Object.create(Symbol.prototype);
// Symbol {}
//   description: (...)
//   __proto__: Symbol
```

Comment: This doesn't construct a new Symbol object instance. It constructs a plain object with Symbol.prototype as its prototype.

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution:

```js
const isFunction = (val) => {
  return typeof val === 'function' || Object.prototype.toString.apply(val) === '[object Function]'
}
```

```js
/**
 * 检测测试数据是否为 JavaScript 内置函数
 * ========================================================================
 * @method isNativeFunction
 * @param {Function|Object} fn - 要测试的函数
 * @returns {Boolean} - fn 是内置函数，返回 true，否则返回 false;
 */
const isNativeFunction = (fn) => {
  return isFunction(fn) && /\{\s*\[native code\]\s*\}/.test('' + fn)
}
```

```js
import isFunction from './isFunction'
import isNativeFunction from './isNativeFunction'

/**
 * 检测测试函数是否为构造函数
 * ========================================================================
 * @method isConstructor
 * @category Lang
 * @param {Function|Object} fn - 要测试的（构造）函数
 * @returns {Boolean} - fn 是构造函数，返回 true，否则返回 false;
 */
const isConstructor = (fn) => {
  const proto = fn.prototype
  const constructor = fn.constructor
  let instance

  if (!isFunction(fn) || !proto) {
    return false
  }

  if (
    isNativeFunction(fn) &&
    (constructor === Function || constructor === fn)
  ) {
    return true
  }

  // 判断 fn 是否为 Promise 构造函数
  instance = new fn()

  // 判断 constructor
  return (
    (instance.constructor === fn && instance instanceof fn) ||
    (instance.constructor === Object && instance instanceof Object)
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you need a solution that works in old browsers ([ES3](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf)+), you can use `instanceof` because it will throw if the right-side operator is not constructor. More exactly, it will throw if the right-side operator is not a function or has no prototype object which in the most common use case is not a constructor. It also works with constructables created with `Function.prototype.bind()` because `instanceof` checks the prototype property of the bound target function.

The Proxy solution provided by Ryan Hanekamp is also incorporated into my answer below because it takes care of edge cases that `instanceof` does not.

```
function isConstructable(value) {
    try {
        typeof Proxy=='function'?
            // Throws if value is not constructable
            new new Proxy(value, {construct:Object})// ES6 needed
        :
            // Throws if not function or target function has no prototype object
            {} instanceof value;
        var isConstructable = true;
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    return !!isConstructable;
}
```