# TypeError: function is not a constructor (evaluating 'new self.f(1)')

Tags: javascript, this, self

I am trying to use a method as a constructor inside another method. But when I do this I get the following TypeError:

`TypeError: function is not a constructor (evaluating 'new self.f(1)')`

and example code is:

```
class C{
        constructor(v){
            this.f(v);
            this.g(v);

        }

        f(v){
            this.v = v;
        }

        g(v){
            var self = this;

            function h(v){
                this.v = v;
                this.w = new self.f(1);
                console.log(this.w);
            }

            new h(1)
        }
    }

var c = new C(1);
```

is there a reference error with self?

Comment: *"is there a reference error with self?"* - No. If you try `var x = new this.f(1);` just before the `function h()` declaration you'll see that that doesn't work either.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm interested in why you can't use a class method as a constructor. I thought the new "class" syntax is just syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Yeah, I don't know the answer here, I only knew enough to note that the `self` part wasn't the issue. The `class` syntax is sugar, but (evidently) it's also a bit more complicated than that...

Comment: Interesting. `this.f.prototype` is also `undefined`, so yea, it can't be used as a constructor.

Comment: @dfsq Even if I define `C.f.prototype = {constructor: C.f}` it still doesn't let me use it as a constructor. There must be something more going on.

Comment: @nnnnnn Apparently the new method definition and class definition in ES6 are not actually just syntactic sugar. Functions created as methods and as arrow functions [do not implement the `[[Construct]]` internal method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40922715/283863).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I think we could close it as duplicate to your linked question. Because the answer contains all informations.

Comment: @t.niese They are related but not necessarily a duplicate in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MDN: Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

> Method definitions are not constructable
>   All method definitions are not constructors and will throw a TypeError if you try to instantiate them.

One reason why the standard defined it that way, might be that you could use `super.foo()` within a method definition. But if you would use this method as a constructor then there would be class you inherit from, so a `super.foo()` would fail.