# What is the difference between these object literals?

Tags: javascript

I created two Objects. The first one is working as intended.

```
let working = {constructor: function(){
  console.log("working");
}};

let notworking = {constructor(){
  console.log("notworking");
}}

new working.constructor();
new notworking.constructor();
```

But the second one throws an Error. The Error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: notworking.constructor is not a constructor
```

Tested on Firefox and Chrome.

In Firefox DevTools the Object itself looks the same. There is a difference in the constructor method.
The working constructor has properties arguments, caller, length and name.
The notworking constructor has only the properties length and name.

So what is the difference between these two objects or constructors?

Comment: the second "object" has no key (separated with a `:`) and a missing semicolon

Comment: Why are you using object literal notation to create an object with a constructor? Why not use a `class` or a `function`?

Comment: https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/not-every-javascript-function-is-constructable/

Comment: @NicoRichter: please note that you can replace `constructor` with any name (`foo`) and this still holds, plain functions are constructable, methods (and arrow functions) are not.

Comment: constructor: ()=>{console.log("notworking")}

Comment: "*The working constructor has properties arguments, caller, length and name.*" - you forgot about [the most important one: `.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48891399/1048572) :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: function is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447648/typeerror-function-is-not-a-constructor-evaluating-new-self-f1)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I just played around with different types of how to create Objects. So for me it was just for interest, why there is a difference. I believed that doing the notworking one is like a already defined variable used in an object literal where name and value are set automatically i.e. let x=1; let y = {x}

Comment: Also related: [Constructor behaving differently using ES6 shorthand notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193117/constructor-behaving-differently-using-es6-shorthand-notation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second syntax is the method syntax and it was introduced in ECMAScript 2015. They are *almost* equivalent, but there's a difference. In the first object, `constructor` is just a key whose value is a function. In the second object, `constructor` is a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). **Method definitions are not constructable**

> Methods cannot be constructors. They will throw a TypeError if you try to instantiate them

From: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#method_definitions_are_not_constructable)

Comment: Great catch. While most people seem to be rather aware that arrow functions cannot be used as constructors,, this particular rule is not that well known.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Never heard of this before. Is there a way to check which type the function is and convert between these different function types? I have seen, that if you create a class the properties of methods are the same as methods.

Comment: @NicoRichter No, you cannot convert them - they're meant for different purposes. And you also shouldn't try checking the type of the function, just try to call it with or without `new` and it will throw an exception if the caller of your code passed the wrong kind - document which one you expect and that's it. But if you absolutely need to, [there are ways to test for functions being constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40922531/1048572). Pre-ES6, the existence of a `.prototype` property on the function is also a pretty good indicator.