# Javascript new keyword

Tags: javascript, new-operator

What does it mean when the instance is created in the following way?

```
somevar = new Person.doSomething()
```

is this a shortcut to create the instance and call the method , like

```
person = new Person ()
person.doSomething()
```

or is it something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Person type matter; If it is a `function` or a `class`?

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A doesn't really matter - as long as `doSomething` is a constructable function.

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A actually the new operator allways calls the constructor() of an object. So it doesn't matter if it's a class or a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this does not create a new instance of `Person` and then call a method on it. It creates an instance of whatever `Person.doSomething()` is. So, in effect, you these two are equivalent:

```js
const Person = {
  doSomething: function(foo, bar){
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

//create a new instance of `Person.doSomething`
const p1 = new Person.doSomething(1, "one");

//take a reference of `Person.doSomething`
const temp = Person.doSomething;
//create an instance of it
const p2 = new temp(2, "two");

console.log("p1:", p1);
console.log("p1 instanceof Person.doSomething:", p1 instanceof Person.doSomething);

console.log("p2:", p2);
console.log("p2 instanceof Person.doSomething:", p2 instanceof Person.doSomething);
```

You can only get instances using *constructable* functions. These are plain functions (declared with the `function` keyword)  and `class` constructors:

```js
function PlainConstructable(a, b) {
  this.foo = a;
  this.bar = b;
}

const plainInstance = new PlainConstructable("plain", "instance");

class ClassConstructable {
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.foo = a;
    this.bar = b;
  }
}

const classInstance = new ClassConstructable("class", "instance");


console.log(`plainInstance:
  instanceof PlainConstructable: ${plainInstance instanceof PlainConstructable}
  what it holds: ${JSON.stringify(plainInstance)}`);
  
console.log(`classInstance:
  instanceof ClassConstructable: ${classInstance instanceof ClassConstructable}
  what it holds: ${JSON.stringify(classInstance)}`);
```

Non-constructable are:

- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [shorthand methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Description) in objects or classes
- most built-in functions (exceptions are explicitly mentioned in documentation)

```js
const arrowFunction = () => {};

const plainObject = {
  shorthandMethod() {}
}

try {
  new arrowFunction();
  console.log("Constructing arrow function successful.");
} catch(e) {
  console.log(
    `Cannot construct arrow function
     ${e}`
   )
}

try {
  new plainObject.shorthandMethod();
  console.log("Constructing shorthand method successful.");
} catch(e) {
  console.log(
    `Cannot construct shorthand method
     ${e}`
   )
}

try {
  new parseInt();
  console.log("Constructing built-in successful.");
} catch(e) {
  console.log(
    `Cannot construct built-in
     ${e}`
   )
}
```

[For more information about constructable functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922531/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-function-is-a-constructor)

Comment: Thank you. It turns out it works only functions with 'function' keyword are construct-able, as I understand it.

Comment: @flag81 yes, that is correct. If you have arrow function `() => {}` or shorthand methods `foo = { bar() {} }` those are not constructable. Although you can also construct classes - `class Foo { constructor(a, b) {} }` can be instantiated with `new Foo`. Classes are mostly syntactic sugar over existing functions, though so the previous desugars to a plain old `function Foo(a, b){}`

Comment: @flag81 I've updated the answer with what I said in the comment about constructable functions. Hope it helps.