# Differentiate function and constructor in runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, types

In TypeScript, I'm writing a function that takes an `Error` factory as an argument: either a class name or a factory function. Something like the below:

```js
// Alias from class-transformer package
type ClassConstructor<T> = {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
};

function doSomething(value: number, errorFactory: () => Error | ClassConstructor<Error>) {
  if (value === 0) {
    // Zero is not allowed
    if (/* errorFactory is a class constructor */) {
      throw new errorFactory()
    } else {
      throw errorFactory()
    }
  }
}
```

In the above function, `errorFactory` can be an `Error` class, such that the following code works:

```js
doSomething(0, Error);
```

Or it can be a function that creates an `Error`:

```js
doSomething(0, () => new Error());
```

The issue is that `ClassConstructor` is a TypeScript type, so it doesn't survive compilation to JavaScript.

`typeof(Error)` is `function`, and so is `typeof(()=>{})`.

So how to determine the parameter's type? What should be the test in `/* errorFactory is a class constructor */`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) will help

Comment: Unless you want to risk invoking it in a `try/catch` you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922531/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-function-is-a-constructor

Comment: Please either add a `class-transformer` tag to the question or try to remove the question's apparent dependency on it.  If it's a simple type alias for `(new (...args: any) => Error)` then you can use it and not mention `ClassConstructor` at all.

Answer (score -1):

By the above code, I understood you need to invoke the constructor with `new`, and the function without `new`.

In the above example, `Error` actually can be invoked without `new`, it can be called just by typing:

```js
throw Error(msg); // msg: string = The error message
```

The code below can be used for testing if the function (or constructor) must be called with `new`:

```js
// Returns:
// - True if the 'func' must be called with 'new'
// - False if the 'func' can be called without 'new'
function isConstructor(func) {
  try {
    // Invoke without 'new'
    func();
  }
  catch (err) {
    if (/^TypeError:.*?constructor/.test(err.toString())) {
      // The error is about that it isn't a normal function
      return true;
    }
    else {
      // The error isn't about that; let's throw it
      throw new err.constructor(err.toString().substr(err.toString().indexOf(" ") + 1), {cause: err});
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Let's run some tests
console.log(isConstructor("abc".constructor)); // False
// String() returns empty string; it's not a constructor
console.log(isConstructor(() => {}));          // False
// Arrow function
console.log(isConstructor(class {}));          // True
// This *is* a cliss
console.log(isConstructor(Image));             // True
// Some built-in cannot be invoked without 'new'
console.log(isConstructor(throwErr));          // TypeError: Another error
function throwErr() {
  throw new TypeError("Another error");
}
```

Comment: `throw err;` <-- Doing this will cause information-loss in the thrown `Error` object (e.g. resetting the stack-trace and other properties) - instead of doing `throw err;` we should throw a new Error and store `err` in that new Error as `cause`: `throw new Error( "human-readable message goes here", { cause: err } );`

Comment: How could this help? `isConstructor` returns `false` for `Error` and `() => new Error`: https://jsfiddle.net/wp9xsk4h/ The question is how a class can be distinguished from a function.