# Strongly typed method to convert object properties as InstanceType or as is

Tags: typescript

I need to make a strongly typed method called *Instantiate* that accept object of any type.

if the object contain any property as class, then it will make the instance of that class, so the return of that object properties should be *InstanceType* of that class

if not a class then it will remain as is.

my problem is I cannot write the correct return type.
the value is not match the key of the original object.

please ignore the body/implementation of method *Instantiate*.
will handle my self. I just need to have the correct typescript typing.

Here is what I try so far.

```
class Person {
    name!: "John Doe"
}

class Cat {
    scream!: "Help!!!"
}

const configApp = {
    isComplicated: true
}

const testData = {
    person: Person, 
    cat: Cat, 
    config: configApp,

} as const

type TClass = abstract new (...args: any) => any;
type TInstances<OBJ> = Record<
    keyof OBJ, 
    OBJ[keyof OBJ] extends TClass
        ? InstanceType<OBJ[keyof OBJ]>
        : OBJ[keyof OBJ]
>;

const instantiate = <T ,>(obj:T): TInstances<T> => { return {} as any}

// Below should not error
const result = instantiate(testData);
result.person.name; //  Error
result.cat.scream;  // Error
result.config.isComplicated; // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sTICECzyCwkUmIWeztvzhewxdLVSMC3sjmcrjyXizOfrfqAA)

Comment: When you say "type safe" what do you mean? Generally that means it will prevent you from doing things that are wrong, but you've already got your classes without their properties assigned, and the implementation of `instantiate` returns `any`. So if you want a solution where `result.person.name.toUpperCase()` doesn't give you a compiler error, then you're asking for something *unsafe*. Could you [edit] the example so that such problems don't occur? In other words: could you make this a [mre] that doesn't introduce issues you're not asking about? Maybe *safety* isn't what you care about at all?

Comment: (see prev comment) If you don't care about safety but just want typings that work as you say, then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlorXw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz thank you a lot. its exactly what I need. can you write as answer?

Comment: I wrote an answer. I hope you don't mind that I edited the question to refer to "strongly typed" instead of "type safe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want `instantiate` to have the following type:

```
declare const instantiate: <T extends object>(obj: T) =>
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends new () => infer I ? I : T[K] }
```

The return type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T`, where each property type is checked via [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) whether it can be used as a no-arg constructor. If not, we leave the property type alone; otherwise we replace it with its instance type (as [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) from the property type).

This gives you the behavior you wanted for your example:

```
const result = instantiate(testData);
/* const result: {
    readonly person: Person;
    readonly cat: Cat;
    readonly config: {
        isComplicated: boolean;
    };
} */
```

So that's the answer to the question as asked.

---

Do note that actually *implementing* `instantiate` correctly will be tricky to get right. You'd need at runtime some way of looking at an arbitrary value and deciding whether it's a no-arg constructor, so that you can presumably write `new value()` to get an instance. But there isn't really a failsafe way to do find out if something is a constructor. You can check if a value is a function, and if its [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) is zero, but not all functions can be called as constructors (e.g., [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) and not all of those that can be so called are *intended* to be used as constructors. See [How to check if a Javascript function is a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40922531/2887218). If someone calls

```
const hmm = instantiate({ a: () => 1 })
//    ^? const hmm: {a: () => 1}
```

then the call signature I've presented will show that `hmm.a` is a function, but at runtime, who knows what will happen. It all depends on your implementation of `instantiate`. And a naive implementation of `instantiate` will quite possibly have a runtime error.

These might be edge cases you don't care about, but you should at least be aware of them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGn6aYAtvAIQBc0ARAFIoAWGAIivFdgL7baiQwDCYAC5Zc+CMETxiFagAl4IAA6lV7Lj3QQRwdADMAlgHMAgkqXQAvKPzQDEfiiJKQB4MPgATSkMQBXeE5uXTRtaCF4bSZhMCsbfCUkVDRKBGR0ABoxPHchSkEhLNsQwyNKEuMzJSyOaEhoEO1ubE94XikGrREDUKEwNCEDD0oAHgAVaHgADwi0TxgUACMAKzahAD4ACiXlyjGASit17KxoAG0AaTsMAGt4AE8UPWgxgF09y9fJmfg5mDR4AB3aCbQ6WdbXPRIaAASWgAH5YdAPhcvhpGiIpBA-CARNYetp+oMPJsIlEYvsANzYAD0ACpOr1oFicXl4ngpGBPOgQPdoIl0ik4El0NTbJzuWheQ1hPlhGL8BKeXyKmV2bY7A4nC43B5vNBFigUCBpGgFXgONTanSadgWbiAHQC5IOwgkan2oQO3IOiScogeyKs736YwO+yOZyuXJeanBLrQehEIhxAl9AZDCKbTB1Sigo7QACM0A4+1pNNsAD1ERjE8nKJgwHmwRDC1wgA)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, tips, explanation and warning that could happen. Very appreciate it. In actual code I use a decorator, so I only instantiate when it have my custom decorator class